# Chebyshev and Hoeffding Inequality

Tags: probability, statistics

I am kind of stuck on a problem that goes as follows.

There are two coins in front of you, one is fair, the other has probability 3/4 of ‘Heads’. You take one of the two coins (without knowing if it is the fair one or the other one), and toss it n times. Let $X_n=\frac{number.\: of\: heads}{n}$

(a) How would you make a prediction (from the value of Xn) on whether the coin is the fair one or the biased one?

b) Using Chebyshev’s inequality, show that for n ≥ 320, the prediction is correct with probability at least 95%.

(c) Using Hoeffding’s inequality, show that for n ≥ 119, the prediction is correct with probability at least 95%.

So I managed to calculate the Variance of the binomial random variable but, the thing I dont understand is how we can show with 95% with out a value of $\epsilon$, would I be solving for 0.95 and trying to find epsilon in this case ? I just wanted to confirm.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is your test defined? Or, equivalently, following what rule is your prediction made?

Comment: I thought part (a) of the question was irrelevant but now that you mention it, I guess it is part of the question. So I'm pretty clueless about this but my guess was to compare the expected value of the random variables from the 2 coins and compare it ? I am not sure if that is correct though. It would be nice if I can get some help

Comment: The problem is that you give some exact numbers in part b) and c) (e.g.: 320). These depend on the test you do. So the test can't be chosen freely in order to get the result you want. If I manage I will write an answer with a test, in which results are a little different from what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of making a prediction.

Let us denote by $p$ the mean of the Bernoulli trials. We have two complementary hypothesis:

- $H_0$ is the hypothesis $p = 1/2$
- $H_1$ is the hypothesis $p = 3/4$

We could define the following test:

- We accept $H_0$ if and only if the empirical mean $\overline{X}:= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is less or equal then $5/8$ (i.e.: the empirical mean is nearer to $1/2$ then to $3/4$).

What is the probability of the prediction being wrong? $$\mathbb{P}(\text{ wrong estimate }| p = 1/2) = \mathbb{P}(\overline{X} > 5/8 | p = 1/2)$$

We find:

- Chebychev: $$\mathbb{P}(\overline{X} > 5/8 | p = 1/2) \le \mathbb{P}(|\overline{X} - 1/2|^2 > 1/64 | p = 1/2) \le \frac{1/4}{n (1/64)} = 0.05 \text{ if n = $320$ } $$
- Chernoff: $$\mathbb{P}(\overline{X} - 1/2 > 1/8 | p = 1/2) \le e^{-2n(1/64)} \approx 0.024 \text{ if $n = 119$ }$$

Similarly one can deal with:

$$ \mathbb{P}(\text{ wrong estimate }| p = 3/4) = \mathbb{P}(\overline{X} \le 5/8 | p = 3/4)  $$

So the $\epsilon$ you were missing in the variance is actually imposed by the test you choose.

P.s.: you might see that with this test you get that Chernoff errs with probability less then $5\%$ already after $96$ trials.

Furthermore you should notice that since Chernoff does not depend on the distribution (but only on the boundedness of the distribution) you do not have to check the Chernoff estimate again in the second case ($p= 3/4$).

Comment: Just a note: while half-way point is a good decision boundary in this case, it would not be the case for probabilities far away from $\frac 1 2$.

Comment: @A.S. This makes sense :) just for general curiosity (since I forgot most of my statistics), do you measure the goodness of the test by how powerful it is?  Is the likelihood ratio test the most powerful in this case?

Comment: I don't know those details, but to me its seems like the decision boundary should satisfy $P(X_1>t)=P(X_2<t)$ sans discretization issues which I don't think translates to likelihood ratios. Since the ration of standard deviations is $\sqrt 3/2\approx 0.866$, this should approximately be the ratio of the segments that the decision point creates in $[\frac 1 2,\frac 3 4]$ (closer to $\frac 3 4$) ($\approx 0.634$). Likelihood ratio yields $\log_3 2\approx 0.631$. Compare with midpoint $0.625$

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

(a) For this question, I would use maximum likelihood to make my prediction. We can imagine this as a statistical test. We have a random variable $X_n\approx Bin(n, p)$, and our goal is to make a decision as to whether:
$$H_o:\ p = 1/2$$ 
$$H_1:\ p = 3/4$$
The likelihood for a Binomial variable in this case is given by:
$$\mathcal{L}(p) = {n \choose X_n}p^{X_{n}}(1-p)^{n-X_n}$$
Now we can simply compare the likelihoods under each hypothesis, and choose the hypothesis with maximum value, according to Bayes' decision rule. Stating this as a likelihood ratio:
$$\hat{P}=3/4 \iff\left(\frac{P_1}{P_0}\right)^{X_{n}}\left(\frac{1-p_1}{1-p_0}\right)^{n-X_{n}} > 1$$
$$\hat{P}=1/2 \iff\left(\frac{P_1}{P_0}\right)^{X_{n}}\left(\frac{1-p_1}{1-p_0}\right)^{n-X_{n}} < 1$$

(b) and (c) are a little bit more involved. But, if we plug in $p_0,\ p_1$ and $n$, we can equate the above inequalities to 1 and solve for $X_n$. 
$$\left(\frac{6}{4}\right)^{X_{n}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{320-X_{n}} =1\rightarrow X_n=201.9$$
That is our decision boundary for predicting $p$. Using Chebyshev's inequality, we can then bound the probability of making an error larger than this under each of the probabilities. We have two equally probable cases now, I will address one, and the other is symmetric:

$P=1/2$:
$$\mu = n*p = 160$$
$$\epsilon = 202-160 = 42$$
$$P(|X_n-\mu|>\epsilon)<\frac{V(X_n)}{\epsilon^2}=\frac{np(1-p)}{\epsilon^2}=0.0454$$

We can use exactly the same ideas to solve for the case $p=3/4$. I assume it will be an even smaller probability of error, since the maximal variance for a binomial distribution is at $p=1/2$. Then, we can repeat this process plugging in Hoeffgding's inequality instead of Chebyshev's, but the process will be identical.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !